# ReferenceError: require is not defined - on Ubuntu 18.04 64bit VPS server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

I got a `ReferenceError` on my build React application which I already host on VPS server.

Whole website is working correctly, except my blog post page. When I try to open certain post which includes `<TwitterTweetEmbed />` component from `"react-twitter-embed"` package, this is the moment when site is crashing and throwing this error (other posts without `<TwitterTweetEmbed />` are working):

[image]

And everything on my development environment is working correctly, which makes me think it's something about this package and node version, or Ubuntu environment. Can someone help me with that?

Ubuntu server is:

- Ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Nodejs version:

- v16.14.2

NPM version:

- v8.6.0

My development version is:

- nodejs: v16.13.0
- npm: v8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

In this case it was nothing about the Ubuntu server and environment.

I fixed this simply by declaring my own `<TwitterTweet />` component based on this package, but I changed the `var script = require('scriptjs');` statement to `import script from 'scriptjs';` so in the end it's compiled to something like `var script = _interopDefault(require('scriptjs'));`

More details could be found on this github issue:
https://github.com/saurabhnemade/react-twitter-embed/issues/105#issue-1195736531